# sbt-launch can't see "group" %% "artifact"

Tags: sbt

How can I tell sbt-launch to look for a `"group" %% "artifact"` style slug instead of a `"group" % "artifact"` style one?

I have published my project into a my-own-HTTP repository.
It resolves just fine from SBT-propper.
But ... I want to launch my program from `sbt-launch` like all the cool kids do.

I need to replace the `stb/sbt.boot.properties` file right?

When I add my repository sbt-launch looks for my stuff in `my/group/name/artifact/version/artifact-version.jar` which doesn't work.
Since my stuff is built with Scala - I need it to look for `my/group/name/artifact_{scala_version}_{sbt_version}/version/artifact-version.jar`

... so ... how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project began life as `sbtPlugin := true` which seems to be the source of my woes.
Dropping this line (and removing my `AutoPlugin`) meant that it now works fine with `sbt-launch`.